# Anylogic block Exit & Enter to move agents to the first free queue

Tags: exit, anylogic, enter

Could anybody tell how I can make my agents move from the Exit to the Enter block linked to the first available queue. In other words, I need an agent is teleported to a Queue block which queueSize gets zero first. Thank you for any help.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUY0f.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I would use a "Wait" block right after your first queue element. I would assign a capacity of 1 to this "Wait" block. I would also create a variable of type 'Enter', let's name it emptyEnter.

`On enter` field of the "Wait" block, use the following:

```
if( queue011.size() == 0 )
{
   wait.freeAll();
   emptyEnter = enter01;
}

else if( queue012.size() == 0 )
{
   wait.freeAll();
   emptyEnter = enter02;
}
    
etc.
```

In the `On Exit` field of your exit block, write the following:

```
emptyEnter.take(agent);
```

Similarly, in the `On Exit` field of each queue, write the following:

```
if(self.size() == 0 )
{
  wait.freeAll();
  emptyEnter = enter01;
}
```

Replace enter01 which the corresponding enter block for each queue element.

Each time an agent leaves a queue, if the queue is empty, the agent is freed from the wait block and sent to the proper enter block.

Let me know if this works for you.